# Accessing elements in a multidimensional array by position

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array. And in the following two functions I want to set the first ("file/1349/powerpoint-examples/") and the second element ("file/1350/powerpoint-examples/") in the first array.
The way I am currently doing it does not work. For **exampleInput**, I get both: "file/1349/powerpoint-examples/", "file/1350/powerpoint-examples/" and for **exampleOutput** I get undefined.

```
visualEnhancement: [
        ["file/1349/powerpoint-examples/", "file/1350/powerpoint-examples/"],
        ["file/1581/powerpoint-examples/", "file/1582/powerpoint-examples/"],
        ["file/1584/powerpoint-examples/", "file/1585/powerpoint-examples/"]
      ]

exampleInput() {

      if (this.example == "Visual enhancement") {
        let i = [0][0];
        return this.imgSrc + this.visualEnhancement[i];
      }
    },
    exampleOutput() {
      console.log(this.example);
      if (this.example == "Visual enhancement") {
        let i = [0][0];
        return this.imgSrc + this.visualEnhancement[i];
      }
```